# With ruby on rails and devise, how to create another model instance belonging to a user that has just registered (i.e. for the first time)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've been looking a few hours in order to find best practices to the following problem: each time a new user registers on my app (with devise), I want to create 3 default Wishlists that will belong to this new user so that he/she can fill them in later on.

```html
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wishlists, dependent: :destroy
end

class Wishlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have read some posts on apparently similar topics but never satisfying my need, which was, in particular, to not modify the registration form and to get the user_id in order to properly create the associated wishlists.

So here is the solution I finally used (below as an answer), should someone have the same issue.

Do better practices exist? Happy to read your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably when your users register this creates a new `user` record? If so I would place your functionality into the `user` model as a callback.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wishlists, dependent: :destroy

  after_create :build_default_wishlists

  def build_default_wishlists
    self.wishlists << Wishlist.new(title: 'Hotels')
    self.wishlists << Wishlist.new(title: 'Food & Drinks')
    self.wishlists << Wishlist.new(title: 'Sightseeing')
  end 

  ...

end
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. This also works very well and as @Sunil D. said, there are indeed less DB queries. I'll replace what I did with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used was to overwrite Devise Registration controller that way :

```html
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController


  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    hotels = Wishlist.create!(title: 'Hotels', user: User.find(resource.id))
    restaurants = Wishlist.create!(title: 'Food & Drinks', user: User.find(resource.id))
    sightseeing = Wishlist.create!(title: 'Sightseeing', user: User.find(resource.id))
    root_path
  end

end
```

Comment: Why not add a `before_create` method on the user to create the wishlists, while the user is being signed up?

Comment: It all gets the job done, but since we're here... you're doing 6 database queries above, 3 times to find the user (avoidable) and 3 tiems to create wish lists.  If you do it as suggested in the answer above there are only 3 calls to the database (b/c the user is already known).